First record with a specific value in a window partition
I have the data below in a SQL Server database.  For each customer_id I want to return the record (row_id is fine) of the FIRST date the customer has no orders.



row_id
customer_id
date
order_count




1
1
2024-01-01
2


2
1
2024-01-02
1


3
1
2024-01-03
5


4
1
2024-01-04
0


5
1
2024-01-05
3


6
2
2024-01-01
5


7
2
2024-01-02
3


8
2
2024-01-03
9


9
2
2024-01-04
1


10
2
2024-01-05
3


11
3
2024-01-01
0


12
3
2024-01-02
1


13
3
2024-01-03
5


14
3
2024-01-04
0


15
3
2024-01-05
3



For this data set I would expect to see these results



customer_id
row_id




1
4


2
null (ideally return null rather than not returning the customer at all)


3
11



So the question is, what does this SQL look like?  I'm thinking a window function partitioned by customer_id, but not sure what the calculation looks like.
Thanks!

why not just select customer_id, min(row_id) from yourtable where ordercount = 0 group by customer_id. Or does the 0 row data not exist at all?

Seems you should use a conditional aggregate. Then you get every customer, regardless of if they have a row with no orders:
SELECT customer_id,
       MIN(CASE order_count WHEN 0 THEN row_id END) AS row_id
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY customer_id;


Select 
yt.row_id, yt.Customer_id,
MIN(case when yt.order_count=0 then yt.order_count else null End) OVER(Partition By yt.Customer_id Order BY yt.order_count) as OrderID
From YourTable yt


Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?

@JeremyCaney Each row retains its individuality, and we get a detailed view of how order_count is compared within each customer. Partitioning can offer several advantages for your database testing and development, such as faster queries, easier maintenance, and higher availability. This can improve the response time and throughput of your queries, especially if you use indexes and partitions wisely. You can perform these operations on individual partitions instead of the whole table, which can reduce the locking, logging, and resource consumption.

That’s useful. Please [edit] your answer to include that information.
